# Relatórios com Jasper reports

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jasper-reports, jasper

Boa noite pessoal! Pra criar relatórios com Jasper eu preciso ter classes com modelos? Sendo que já tenho um banco populado e quero apenas os relatórios, criando filtros e tals...

Comment: Classe como modelos e o padrão bean (pojo) hibernate utiliza esta técnica, você também pode ter relatórios baseados na consulta SQL nativa do banco aí vc iria colocar os parâmetros Diretamente no jasper Reports ou ireport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem duas formas de popular um relatório no JasperServer:

1) Você pode criar a query no próprio Jasper, e não vai precisar de nenhuma entidade do JAVA.
O JasperServer fornece a possibilidade de criar querys dinâmicas passando parâmetros via Java para o Jasper caso seja necessário.

2) Criar um DTO e popular ele com os dados necessários e passar isso para o Jasper.

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa ser com beans, jasper aceita várias formas de conexão, incluindo via SQL diretamente no relatório ou por parâmetros dinâmico caso precise de uma consulta Dinamica